# Is it safe to seal the seams/gaps on washer and dryer units?

Tags: safety, dryer, washing-machine, ventilation, sealing

Specifically, I have the following model units:

Maytag Washer WTW8040DW
Maytag Gas Dryer WGD8000DW4

The units come with open seams, and I'd like to know if it's safe to seal these?  Surprisingly, Google search didn't net any relevant results for me, and there's no mention in the manuals either.  I'd be using either 100% silicone, alex caulk, or some other sealant depending on safety implications.

EDIT: Here's a photo for clarification:
[image: Photo]

EDIT2: The objective I'm trying to achieve is sound- & vibration-dampening.  Please note that I have already implemented most standard "fixes" (see comments below), but short of purchasing actual soundproofing out-of-pocket, I believe this would achieve some functional effect.  I only want to make certain that there is no safety concerns with proceeding.

Comment: When you say "seams", are you referring to the gaps between the panels in the outer cover? Were the panels not installed properly, or are there just the normal, small gaps between panels? Maybe include a picture of what you mean by "open seams" - that will help determine if they're normal or not. _Why_ do you want to seal them? If either unit _ever_ needs service, these "seams" are where the panels come apart so someone can get in there to fix it.

Comment: @freeman Photo added for clarification!  Primarily for noise reduction and vibration dampening, but if there's any benefit to air/thermal insulation that'd be great as well.  I can always cut out the sealant and reapply in the event access is required.

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Those look like perfectly normal panel gaps to me. I'd suggest that to reduce noise, getting the units off the hardwood floor with some sort of cushioning  would be more effecting. Either that or pack a few more dogs around it. ;)

Comment: Your first priority should be whether is will ruin your adorable puppy's cozy space!  He's there for a reason! :)

Comment: The house belongs to my in-laws, and they have absolutely zero concept regarding home improvement / maintenance.  The walls are so sparse you can feel the vibrations from a door being opened as silently as possible from any room in the residence.  I've done a lot of work over the past 12 months, but the washer & dryer remain a nuisance despite applying all the tricks I know of (calking, felt pads & stands, weatherstripping, door sweeps, hammer arrestors, insulating hoses and duct, etc.).  I'd move on to actual soundproofing except all this is coming out of my pocket.

Comment: We have opposite sleep schedules and their room is right above ours, so noise output is a constant concern.

Comment: @freeman Edited to include additional clarification, I've already implemented suggested steps (and it's tile, not hardwood, if that makes any difference).  I've also considered filling the doors / walls with insulation foam as a more economical alternative to soundproofing, but I'd rather not chance the plumbing, and with the doors it'd be a pain to replace if any mishaps were to occur.

Comment: You might consider placing a stack or two of folded towels on top of the W/D set when they're running, just to see if/how much that deadens the noise. That may give you an idea of whether adding any sound proofing to the appliance would help. If it doesn't, you may have to look into sound proofing the whole room. (To some level of "soundproof".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to seal the housing seams with silicone caulk. You aren't going to cause fire or electrical problems doing so (within reason). Use a fine tip and press it in firmly so as to not make a goopy mess of your appliance.

However, I don't think this will accomplish your goal. If the unit is shaking around so much that it's squeaking and buzzing it needs other repair. If not, the sound will make its way out underneath or elsewhere anyway. Adding foam insulation inside could cause heat problems. There's a rather large motor in there, along with heating elements, and the system is designed to manage heat as it is through air convection and metal conduction.

Comment: Thanks!  The units are brand new and properly leveled, the issue isn't that they are operating outside of expected decibel range, I'm simply still in need of further decreasing noise/vibration regardless.